# Reusing ViewModels - State for each screens that will use it

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

According to this [article](https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-3-model-view-viewmodel-e7eeee76b73b):

> The ViewModel should expose states for the View, rather than just
>   events.

I'm reusing viewmodel because I need the **same data for multiple views**, but my doubt here is that **they use the same data but they display it in different ways**. Like for example, if I have a list of users, the **first view displays them**, the **second view** use the data **for sorting purposes**, the **third view displays some label** if the **list of users reached a certain size**.

If I only expose the data (list of users) and the view will decides what to do on it, aside from I'm violating the architecture, it is also hard to test because I need to mock android, but I only want to test if a certain method is called, it doesn't matter how the view displays it.

So I'm thinking of solution like creating a State class for each view that uses the viewmodel so the viewmodel will update the state and I can easily now test if state changes.

My problem here is the more views reusing the view model, the more state for each and every view, it doesn't look right to me also, just imagine the method changing all of the states even though only 1 view at a time can be displayed.

Creating separate viewmodels for each view looks like duplicating the code for me, like for example: `ResetPasswordView` and `CreatePasswordView`, they do both have same process, almost same behavior also, so why not reuse viewmodel? ... or should I? What am I missing here?

**Edit (my current solution):**

From what I did, I've created separate view models for each fragment/activity because **although they use the same data, they represent it differently**. And by doing that, I can make unit tests for the presentation logic because all the data manipulations (specifically for the view) are happening on the view model.

I do share view model but for the purpose of navigation, example is the best way to explain this (I'm using Koin here as my dependency framework):

**OnBoardingActivity**:

```
class OnBoardingActivity {

   var fullNameViewModel by viewModel<FullNameViewModel>()

   private fun initViewModels() {
      fullNameViewModel.stateShowEmail.observe(this, Observer {
         // do navigate to email because that's the next screen/fragment after FullNameFragment
      })
   }
}
```

**FullNameFragment**:

```
class FullNameFragment {

   var viewModel by sharedViewModel<FullNameViewModel>() // notice that I share the view model from the activity here to have only 1 instance

   private fun initViews() {
      RxTextView.textChanges(etFirstName)
         .doOnNext { viewModel.setFirstName(it.toString()) }
         .subscribe()

     // ... set the other fields
   }

   private fun initViewModels() {
      viewModel.stateValidationFirstName.observe(this, Observer {
         when(it) { // validation
            is RequiredValidation -> // show some error/validation message
            else -> it is valid! remove any error/validation messages
         }
      })
   }
}
```

**FullNameViewModel**:

```
class FullNameViewModel {

   val stateValidationFirstName = MutableLiveData<Validation>() // some validation object
   val stateShowEmail = SingleLiveEvent<Any>() // I'm using the hacky single live event here hehe

   fun setFullName() {
      // do the validations, some process and this can be easily test
      // like: stateValidationFirstName = RequiredValidation()

      stateShowEmail.call()
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't make a ViewModel for each individual view. Instead, for each Fragment and / or Activity. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: As of now, I created each and every view a single viewmodel. Though some views use the same data, they render it differently. So it means that they still have their own state, thats why I create different view model for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when an article refers to the view, they don't mean the literal `View` class. They mean it in an architectural sense.

Take MVVM. Model-View-ViewModel.

When we talk about Android, the View is the `Activity`, `Fragment` and `View` layout.

So ideally, you should have one `ViewModel` for the most logical sets.

If you have an `Activity` and a layout, but no `Fragment`, then it makes sense to have one `ViewModel` to cover the `Activity` state, which includes its layout.

If you have an `Activity` with its own layout AND a `Fragment`, then you might have two `ViewModel`s. One for the `Activity` state and one for the `Fragment`.

I wrote a sample App that might help:
https://github.com/DavidEdwards/mvvm-example

Take the example of having a basic `Activity` with no layout except for its `Fragment`. You would have one `ViewModel` in the `Fragment` (typically, this is by no means a rule). In this `ViewModel` you would have `LiveData` representing the state of your `View`s. When you want to change the state of a `View`, you change the state in the `ViewModel`, and the `ViewModel` propagates the changes to the `View`. I will typically accomplish that by passing the `ViewModel` into my layouts using the excellent [Android Databindings Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding).

You can see an example of that [here](https://github.com/DavidEdwards/mvvm-example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/dae/rounder/ui/fragments/GameFragment.kt#L35), [here](https://github.com/DavidEdwards/mvvm-example/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_game.xml#L6) and [here](https://github.com/DavidEdwards/mvvm-example/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_game.xml#L28). In this example, I am controlling the visibility of a `View` by observing the state of the number of players in the game.

Comment: From what I did, I create different view models for each fragment, but they are `sharedViewModel`, so the actual `ViewModel` was still on the Activity. I did that because I listen from the activity for the navigation changes (eg: replacing new fragment). As of now, it works for me, because it seems that my view models are break down into chunks, and they are also easy to test. Is this still a good practice or am I violating some part of mvvm?

Comment: I tend to avoid `sharedViewModel` whenever possible. I have only ever really used it to deal with situations such as navigation (where the `Fragment` needs to tell the `Activity` to change the active `Fragment`) or updating the main `Toolbar` title from the `Fragment`. The key is to make sure that your `ViewModel`s are testable (not several per `Fragment` and not one Monolith global shared `ViewModel`). If it is testable, you are probably fine.

Comment: It seems that I'm doing well, I'm just using `sharedViewModel` for navigation purposes. And it is not also hard to test. Thanks for this.